# preventDefault() doesn't work on image link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, hyperlink

i am trying to create a lightbox for my website but i got a problem. Since i am not very fluent in jQuery i do a lot of mistakes. One of them is that i cant make preventDefault() work for both text and image links! Check the following code

**HTML code:**

```
Text link: <a class='ultbox_simg' href='images/1.jpg'>Image 1</a>
Image link: <a href='images/1.jpg'><img src="images/1t.jpg" /></a>
```

**jQuery script:**

```
$(document).ready(function ($){

    $(".ultbox_simg").click(function (obj){
        obj.preventDefault();
        var img_link=$(this).attr("href");

    });
});
```

Comment: why do you need prevent default on an image? you nee to do so on the anchor tag

Comment: Maybe You should add `class` attribute to image link as on the text link is ? `<a href='images/1.jpg' class='ultbox_simg'>`

Comment: @Ibu: The title is (mildly) misleading, but if you look at the code, it's the `a` that he's trying to hook, he's just not hooking both of them.

Answer (score 3):

You could add the class also to the img link:

```
Text link: <a class='ultbox_simg' href='images/1.jpg'>Image 1</a>
Image link: <a class='ultbox_simg' href='images/1.jpg'><img src="images/1t.jpg" /></a> 

$(".ultbox_simg").click(function (obj){
    obj.preventDefault();
    var img_link=$(this).attr("href");

});
```

or  (even better i think), you could traget links with that href:

```
$('a[href="images\\/1\\.jpg"]').click(function (obj){
    obj.preventDefault();
    var img_link=$(this).attr("href");

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should also prevent default action on:

```
<a href='images/1.jpg'>
```

So add class for it for example 'noClick' and add to script:

```
$(".noClick").click(function (obj){
        obj.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add  the class .ultbox_simg to your image link.

```
<a class='ultbox_simg' href='images/1.jpg'><img src="images/1t.jpg" /></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

here is what you need to change:

```
Image link: <a href='images/1.jpg'><img src="images/1t.jpg" /></a>
```

to:

```
Image link: <a href='images/1.jpg'  class='ultbox_simg'><img src="images/1t.jpg" /></a>
```

now it will work

Answer (score 0):

With `$('.ultbox_simg')` you select the elements that have the class `ultbox_simg` and bind the `click` handler to them.

But the image link does not have this class assigned..

so

```
<a class="ultbox_simg" href="images/1.jpg"><img src="images/1t.jpg" /></a>
```